# Wireshark: What is wag-service?

Tags: wireshark

I'm seeing alot of wag-service traffic in wireshark. What is it?

Comment: Didn't get a fast enough answer on superuser?  http://superuser.com/questions/80357/what-is-wag-service

Comment: Also seen on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866861/wireshark-what-is-wag-service

Answer (score 2):

Are you seeing this on the source or destination? If it's on the source don't be thrown off by a red herring. The source machine will pick an available port from the ephemeral port range and sometimes this is a port that's registered to another service. Wag is registered on port 2608 for TCP and UDP so it falls in the ephemeral port range used by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

According to the IANA (see http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers), this service was registered by Gilles Bourquard from wag.ch.

Unfortunately, I don't speak Czech, so the website really doesn't help me, but it looks as if (among other things) they do some sort of CAD -> manufacturing thing. Any automated computer-controlled machinery in your building?

Comment: `ch` is Switzerland and the web site is in German. They are a plastics manufacturer. Google translate is your friend. http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http://www.wag.ch/cgi/wernli.pl&sl=auto&tl=en